# Updated to 15.04, no sound other than startup sound

Tags: sound

I have recently updated from 14.04 to 14.10 and then to 15.04. I now have absolutely no sound other than the startup "drums" sound.

I have tried most things found here, i.e. : reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, checking if there isn't a muted channel on alsamixer, etc.

My first question is: I have speakers connected. Is it normal that the "Sound" options on System Settings only show HDMI (from, I suppose, the screen) and Digital Output? If not, how to fix that?

Secondly: if the problem isn't on my first question, how may I fix this ?

Comment: Try deleting `pulse` under `~/.config`, then rebooting.

Comment: Just did it, nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, well your sound outputs should definitely have an analog output for the speakers, which made me think it was a config problem with `pulseaudio`. I'm not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently installing "PulseAudio Volume Controller" and fiddling in the Configuration solved it. The computer still doesn't recognize the Speakers as plugged in (it literally says "unplugged") but it does work when I select it as an output...